# og image does not download to facebook

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I'm getting the following error:

```
Image Unavailable
Provided og:image, https://sustainablewestonma.org/.swag/uploads/logoCapture.png could not be 
downloaded. This can happen due to several different reasons such as your server using unsupported 
content-encoding. The crawler accepts deflate and gzip content encodings.
```

the file is 252X226 png bit depth 32.  As far as I can tell it is not base64.  I tried to refresh on facebook several times but that didn't work either/

here are the meta tags I'm using:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="SWAG" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:description" content="logo" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="419989405770732" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://sustainablewestonma.org/.swag/public/php/homeCtrl.php?place=first" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://sustainablewestonma.org/.swag/uploads/logoCapture.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

converted the image to an *.ico file and it worked